# Process multiple PHP scripts in one array

Tags: php

I have multiple php scripts to ping each of our locations, and I'm trying to list all results on one page.

Here's the ping script:

```
<?php
  $host  = "10.10.10.10"; //IP adress to ping
  $loc = ("HQ"); //Name of location
  $output = array();
  echo("<b>$loc</b> <i>(IP: $host)</i> is ");
        exec("ping -n 1 $host 2>&1", $output);
     //print_r($output);
      //you can use  print_r($output)  to view the output result
      if (count($output) > 7) {
        $output = null;
        die ("<font color='green'><b>up</b></font>");
        }
        else {
        $output = null;
        die ("<font color='red'><b>down</b></font>");
        }       
?>
```

So, I have many php files with this script, where the only difference is `host` and `loc`.
I've tried to include each file in a new php file using `include` like this:

```
<?php
include "file1.php";
include "file2.php";
include "file3.php";
...and so on...
?>
```

But this only outputs the result of the first file.

How can I do this in any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: using `die` means you are exiting your code. you should use `echo` instead of die

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`die()`, or its equivalent [`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) ends the script. Simply change `die()` to `echo` as in:

```
if (count($output) > 7) {
    $output = null;
    echo "<font color='green'><b>up</b></font>";
} else {    
    $output = null;
    echo "<font color='red'><b>down</b></font>";
}
```